# Will the world end when the first duplicate GUID is generated?

Tags: random, guid, probability

GUIDs are great: a nifty way to generate a unique key whenever you need one. And the pool of possible GUIDs is so incredibly vast that there will never be two identical GUIDs generated!  Woot!

Well, I am just wondering how many algorithms and businesses depending on those algorithms there are that would come crashing down in a flaming heap if, Heaven forbid, a duplicate GUID was ever produced.

Has anyone really thought this through?  I mean, even if there are a trillion different coins in Lake Superior and I pick one out blindfolded and then throw it back again, it is still possible (although very unlikely) that I will pick out the exact same coin the next time isn't it?  Or, at least, that over the next million years of people picking out coins from the lake?

And random numbers are just that: random.  And random means that at every point where the next number is generated, all numbers have the same probability of occurring.

So given that gazilliions of GUIDs must be generated each and every day, how can we be so incredibly confident that there will never be a duplicate?

Is that confidence or arrogance or even stupidity?

Comment: Altough it´s possible, the probabilty is very very very small. And the probabilty that the the guy in Japan with GUID x and the one in Finland with the same GUID will ever meet and/or realize that there is a problem is even smaller. Any question?

Comment: Guids usually include time portion and thus are pretty much guaranteed to be unique for 20-30 years from now.

Comment: A programmer can foresee this possibility and not use GUIDs for critical applications, or prepare for a possible duplicate. The Y2K scare taught some lessons to programmers.

Answer (score 3):

> Will the world end when the first duplicate GUID is generated?

No the world will not end. Instead the world and the people living in it will try to find a solution to this.

But to explain that it would take much of your energy and time to create a duplicate GUID.

The **[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier)** will give you the answer to this:-

> While each generated GUID is not guaranteed to be unique, the total
>   number of unique keys (2^128 or 3.4×10^38) is so large that the
>   probability of the same number being generated twice is very small.
>   For example, consider the observable universe, which contains about
>   5×10^22 stars; every star could then have 6.8×10^15 universally unique
>   GUIDs.

So considering the above fact from the wiki you may think that almost 100% times  you will find that GUID's are unique and will not be repeated. And the possibility that it being duplicated it **1 out of 3.4×10^38** which is probably very low.

Also you may find this interesting to read:- **[GUIDs are globally unique, but substrings of GUIDs aren't](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/06/27/8659071.aspx)**

Also check this article which explains the **[The Great GUID Shortage](http://betterexplained.com/articles/the-quick-guide-to-guids/)**

> When learning about GUIDs, it feels like 39 measly digits aren’t
>   enough. Won’t we run out if people get GUID-crazy, assigning them for
>   everything from their pets to their favorite bubble gum flavor?
>
> Let’s see. Think about how big the Internet is: Google has billions of
>   web pages in its index. Let’s call it a trillion (10^12) for kicks.
>   Think about every wikipedia article, every news item on CNN, every
>   product in Amazon, every blog post from any author. We can assign a
>   GUID for each of these documents.
>
> Now let’s say everyone on Earth gets their own copy of the internet,
>   to keep track of their stuff. Even crazier, let’s say each person gets
>   their own copy of the internet every second. How long can we go on?
>
> Over a billion years.
>
> Let me say that again. Each person gets a personal copy of the
>   internet, every second, for a billion years.
>
> It’s a mind-boggling amount of items, and it’s hard to get our heads
>   around it. Trust me, we won’t run out of GUIDs anytime soon. And if we
>   do?
>
> ## **We’ll start using GUIDs with more digits.**

Comment: Thanks Rahul for the comprehensive answer.  I still think there is an ever-so-slight air of arrogance in assumptions of the kind "It's so incredibly unlikely that it will never happen".  Going on my success with the pokies, lotteries and games of chance in general, I am pretty sure the first 2 GUIDs I will generate in a soon-to-be-released-to-production system will be identical and then there will never be another one for the remainder of eternity ;-)

Comment: @FelixBembrick:- You are welcome! And yes I got your idea and your question but as  user1095108 has already pointed the Y2K scare taught some lessons to programmers and the programmers will definitely try to figure this out too! And yes nobody is denying that this would never ever happen but the case is very very very rare:)

Comment: Yes, I agree.  While Y2K never really eventuated, the lesson contained within the hype is a valuable one and that is probably what I will take away most from this interesting conversation :-)

Answer (score 1):

No, the world will not end when a duplicate is generated, because the consequences of the occasional duplicate are not earthshattering.

How would you even know that it had happened?

Answer (score 1):

No, the world would not end. In fact most likely such an event would never even be noticed or if so would have zero to negligable effect. That can easily be seen if we take a look at ways Guids are actually used:

**Keys for data objects:**
Since uniqueidentifier columns tend to be marked as unique, the database would most likely throw an insert error and you'd just lose a few rows of data. If the duplicate guids were in different tables, you'd end up with a data inconsistency which someone would then have to manually fix. Of course most likely the first duplicate guid would be generated in an entirely different computer system and database, most likely in data decades or thousands of years separated, so the chance of such two keys ever being compared would be miniscule.

**Correlating event logs**
Since this data will tend to be throwaway, at most you'd have a confused programmer wondering how someone else's guid popped up in their log file.

**Unique program section keys**
A clash of this sort would just mean a compile failure and rebuilding with a new key and would not affect production data.

There are of course plenty of other uses of Guids, from web aps to large data-processing systems, but from these examples it should be obvious that first of all two identical guids generated in different countries / systems /times would most likely not meet and if they did the result would be a minor inconvenience and one failed operation.

Now of course one could envision perhaps some kind of disaster where a nuclear power plant controlling program fails at a critical step, leading for instance to improper movement of a control rod and a resulting nuclear meltdown, but first of all that is already badly written software more likely to fail sooner for other reasons and secondly that's not a world-ending event. So basically the likelihood of any world-ending event caused by duplicate guids (or multiple duplicate guids!) and exploding power plants, data centres and launched nuclear warheads can be imagined as similar to the likelihood of the Earth ripping apart or spiralling into the sun due to the sudden random and coincidental movement of all it's constituent particles in a particular direction.
=8)-DX